# What JSP code can display data of linked list?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%LinkedList data=new LinkedList ();%>
```

I have data in the variable "data". How can I display all contents of "data".

Comment: How about a loop ? BTW have you tried `<%=data%>`?

Comment: Thanks dude... you really helped me... :)